# Get only unique names from more elements

Tags: jquery, button, css-selectors, radio-button

I have dynamically rendered HTML that lists an undetermined number of radio buttons whose names represent some ids in a database.

I need to collect all of the unique names of the radios.

Here is an example:

```
<input name="721" type="radio" value="A" />        
<input name="721" type="radio" value="I" />     

<input name="722" type="radio" value="A" />        
<input name="722" type="radio" value="I" />     

<input name="723" type="radio" value="A" />        
<input name="723" type="radio" value="I" />
```

Checking the radios is NOT required, so using a selected or checked attribute won't work.

Is there an elegant way to get all the unique names of the radios using jQuery?
I know I can just loop through each of the radios, but I'm hoping that jQuery has a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ehicis/3/edit)**

```
var arr = [];

$.each( $('input:radio'), function(){

  var myname= this.name;
  if( $.inArray( myname, arr ) < 0 ){
     arr.push(myname); 
  }

});

alert(arr); // 721,722,723
```

Comment: This is really close, so I'll mark this as the answer.  I had to use $.inArray() because IE8 doesn't support arr.indexOf().  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = $('input[type=radio]').map(function() {
    return this.name
}).get(); // create an array of names

var unique = $.grep(names, function(v, i) {
    return $.inArray(v, names) === i
}); // filter unique values
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WnHvz/

Answer (score 1):

To get unique names, you can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to build an array of all the names, then combine [$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) with [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to remove duplicates.

Something like:

```
var allNames = $("input[type=radio]").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("name");
}).get();

var uniqueNames = $.grep(allNames, function(name, index) {
    return $.inArray(name, allNames) == index;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio').each(function(){
    // do something
 });
```

Comment: Thanks - sure this will allow me to do the looping way, but I'm really looking for a selector that'll give me all the names of the radios.  Using the loop above is ineligent because I have to get each name, see if it exists already, and (if not) then add it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - the html you posted doesnt have unique names. There's two of each... but this is how you can get them:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});​
```

Comment: I suppose he could just take the value attribute and append it to the name attribute if he needs unique names.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `print those names` before each `radio` then use it:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    $(this).before($(this).attr('name'));
});​
```

try out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teLjg/

Answer (score 0):

Just try to loop thru and get all the names and store it in an array... then by using filter method you can filter the unique values....

let say,

```
var array=[your array values];

var unique_val = array.filter(function(value,iter,array){
    return iter == array.indexOf(value);
});
```

This might work...

Answer (score 0):

First get a node list of radio items:

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
```

Then get an array of the names, and then make a set out of them, a set by definition only contains unique entries:

```
const radioNames = new Set(Array.from(radios).map( el => el.name))
```

Comment: Just tried to upvote my own answer, at least I am consistent

Answer (score -1):

I think you people so fast and love jQuery, huh.
this may help you, in case of 2 radio buttons,
http://jsfiddle.net/BTcrR/ check this out

```
$(function() {
    // list of 
    var rediobuttonsName = new Array();
    // you can use :odd | :even
    $('input[type="radio"]').not(':odd').map(function(n, elem) {

       rediobuttonsName.push(elem.name);
       // or  you can use the context of object this
       // this.name

   });

   alert(rediobuttonsName);
});​
```

or you can get ride of the .not(":odd") and check the array if it has the value of the name. ;)