# Unique name for Add More input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create an add more button which will create a new input field. However, I would like to have an unique name set for it.

I tried to search up for an answer, [but this does not answer my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112804/get-only-unique-names-from-more-elements).

So, basically **what I tried** to make my namefield unique is to use the php method `rand()`. The concept is that - when the add more button is clicked, it will have a name attached to the number given to me by `rand()`.

However, what happens is that it takes the value generated by `rand()` and applies it to all the names of all the inputs generated.

This is my code and what I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[<?php echo rand(); ?>]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 100; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[<?php echo rand(); ?>]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">Remove</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });

    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, the first field generates the number as intended. If you click on the add more, the second field does create an unique number. However, if you click add more once again, the third field copies the same name as the 2nd field.

How do I go about achieving what I want and why is `rand()` not generating a new code?

Also, does `rand()` guarantee me that it will be an unique ID or is there a chance for it to repeat the same number?

If it does repeat, then what would be the best approach to take to make it as unique as possible?

Comment: php is on the server side - so it is run on the server once ... javascript has `Math.random()`

Comment: So I'll use it like `var x  = Math.random();` ?

Comment: sure, if that works. x will be a decimal number between 0...1 -and of course, there's no guarantee of uniqueness - though, highly unlikely given 16 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random does not necessarily mean unique, even if collisions would be extremely rare. This solution simply increments a `totalFieldsCreated` variable to get the next unique number (up to the maximum value JavaScript can provide.)

The new fields are created dynamically instead of using a fixed string of HTML. (This technique is more flexible.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Defines global identifiers
  let
    currentFieldCount = 1,
    totalFieldsCreated = 1;
  const
    maxFieldCount = 100,
    addButton = $('.add_button'),
    wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');

  // Calls `addField` when addButton is clicked
  $(addButton).click(addField);

  // Executes anonymous function when `Remove` is clicked, which removes
  //   the parent div, and decrements (and logs) `currentFieldCount`
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    currentFieldCount--;
    console.log(`currentFieldCount: ${currentFieldCount}`);
  });

  // Defines the `addField` function
  function addField(){

    // Makes sure that `currentFieldCount` and `totalFieldsCreated` 
    //   are not at maximum before proceeding
    if(
      currentFieldCount < maxFieldCount && 
      totalFieldsCreated < Number.MAX_VALUE
    ){

      // Creates an input element, increments `totalFieldsCreated`,
      //   and uses the incremented value in the input's `name` attribute
      const input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.name = "field" + ++totalFieldsCreated;
      input.value = "";

      // Creates an anchor element with the `remove_button` class
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "javascript:void(0);";
      a.classList.add("remove_button");
      a.title = "remove";
      a.innerHTML = "Remove";
      
      // Adds the new elements to the DOM, and increments `currentFieldCount`
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(input);
      div.appendChild(a);
      $(wrapper).append(div);
      currentFieldCount++;

      // Logs the new values of both variables 
      console.log(
        `currentFieldCount: ${currentFieldCount},`,
        `totalFieldsCreated ${totalFieldsCreated}`
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="" />
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really very good, I've tried it and it works. Yes I agree randomness is not equals to unique. Your solution guarantees unique field names.

Comment: I'm glad it's helpful

Comment: Its an excellent answer, I've went on to do even further testing, and its so good. I tried to add a field, remove it and then re-add and it actually does skip the removed field number increment. Nice work and a big thank you Cat.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate random name with PHP it is done once on the server. Your JS code then copies the same element. What you need is to generate unique names with js.

Avoid random if you can, theoretically, you can hit the same number and run into mysterious bugs.

```
var generateField = function(name)
{
     return '<div><input type="text" name="'+name+'" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">Remove</a></div>'; //New input field html 
}

//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(generateField('field_name['+x+']' ) ); //Add field html
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, yes I understand now why php rand doesn't work. PHP is server side so it requires another click. Cheers man..

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.random()` in js rather than `rand()` in php ,`Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000` will generate a five digit random number , Hope this helps

```js
$('.rand').attr('name',"fields["+Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000+"]")

$('.add_button').click(function(e){

$('.field_wrapper').append('<div><input type="text" name=fields['+Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000+'] value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">Remove</a></div>')

})

$(document).on('click','.remove_button',function(e){

     $(this).parent().remove()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="rand" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this still duplicates the same name from the 2nd field. Only default field and the 1st add more field is unique, but when you add more again once more time (3 fields in total now), you'd realise that field 2 and field 3 has the same name.

Comment: This is weird, on your snippet (after doing an inspect element) I see that all the names are unique. But when I do it on a normal file, it shows that fields 2 onwards, all copies the name of the 2nd field. (add more fields are all the same)

Comment: omg I am so careless, I copied your code into index2.php and I was testing it on index.php (that explains why it was not showing me the correct results). haha, yes your code works like a boss!! Thank you so much my friend!

Comment: Avoid random() values in field names, it will make your code harder to test and opens a possibility of bugs if you hit the same random value twice.